# Enter password on macOS when smart card is available

Tags: macos, password, unlock, touch-id

I have a Yubikey with PIV enabled and paired with my MacBook. I also use Touch ID to unlock  when available. But Touch ID requires the password to re-enable from time to time (e.g. not unlocked for 48 hours, etc.). In this case, I can't enter my password without unplugging the Yubikey (I can enter the PIN to unlock, of course. But that won't re-enable Touch ID). Is there a way to enter the password instead of PIN without unplugging the smart card?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, you can open system preferences, go to users & groups and enter your password.

Another option would be to write a menu bar app that does the same thing. It just needs to use either SFAuthorization, SFAuthorizationPluginView or Local Authentication. A programmer that works in Identity could help you write the status bar app.

Also a tool that verifies your username and password could prevent your touchid from expiring.